# Set the DOCUMENT_ROOT over .htaccess

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible to change the DOCUMENT_ROOT setting in the .htaccess? I was using it this variable to development but the variable value in the remote server has a quite different value I don't have access to.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: you have to be doing something rather odd, to think this is necessary

Comment: I was using it to reference a few files I was including with php but the document_root in the local server is different than the one I deploy the app to.

Comment: and so the files will be in a different location to